# TCPServer AcceptSocket() hangs even though there is a pending connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcplistener

I have a `TCPServer` running for file receiving, and it works 99% of the time, but it will sometimes(randomly it seems) hang on the `AcceptSocket()` line even though I wait for the `Pending()` Flag to be true. Here is the code I am using for the server. (I am aware `Thread.Sleep()` is bleh, but that is not the issue at hand... I don't think).

```
// wait for the file connection
int elapsed = 0; bool timeout = false; int overtime = 60000;
while (fileServer.Pending() == false && (elapsed < overtime))
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    elapsed += 1000;

    if (elapsed > overtime)
       timeout = true;
}

    if (timeout)
    {
       Program.EventMessage("FILE SERVER TIMEOUT, NO FILE RECIEVED");
       incoming_file = false;
       continue;
    }

Program.EventMessage("OPENING SOCKET");
fileSocketForClient = fileServer.AcceptSocket();
```

Basically, since this code *does* work. What would cause the issue of `AcceptSocket()` hanging even though it has a pending connection?

Is there anyway to check to see if the Socket Accepting is blocking that I could implement a timeout?

I'd like for the socket to remain blocking as the rest of the application does need this operation to be completed to move forward, it just needs a timeout or something so if it does crap out, can recover without having to manually restart the entire program.

Issue found, and I know what I need to do to fix it (timeout `AcceptSocket()`), but scrounging around SO I have not found a viable way to do so yet.

As a temporary band-aid I have moved this to multithreaded, so at least when it dies the server can still go... there will just be the forever blocking thread to deal with.

Comment: The `Pending` call doesn't predict the future. That a connection *was* pending in the past doesn't guarantee the connection will still be pending later. If you want socket operations that don't block, use socket operations that don't block.

Comment: but Pending call determines if it has an incoming connection. no?

Comment: At the time it returned, yes. But that doesn't predict the future. The connection may not be pending later, say because the other side closed it. If you want non-blocking socket operations, use non-blocking socket operations.

Comment: Is your real question "How to make AcceptSocket time out?". Your code is blocking at the moment due to the sleep so being non-blocking cannot be your goal.

Comment: that is pretty much what I want to achieve, yes.

Answer (score 0):

A connection *was* pending. Does that mean a connection will still be pending later? No. Status functions don't predict the future.

"I'm smart enough to think of every possible way a socket operation could block and make sure that doesn't happen, so I can use blocking socket operations and still be assured they'll never block." No, you aren't. Don't even try. It won't work. Use non-blocking socket operations.

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation from the downvoter. If I'm unclear, I'd like to know what needs to be clarified. If I'm incorrect, I'd like to know how.

Comment: David, just suggest using threads, and you'll get ton of reps from the kiddies </sarcasm>.

Comment: Although it does give insight to what can be happening, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: The answer is to use non-blocking socket operations, as I said. Blocking socket operations are almost impossible to get right.